# Android Retrofit Only one encoding annotation allowed

Tags: android, xml, retrofit2

I want to make an API call using Retrofit.
The call will basically send some data, together with an image.
This is what I've written:

```
@POST("notes/new")
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Note> getData (@Field("title") String title,
                    @Field("note") String note,
                    @Header("Authorization") String auth,
                    @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                    @Part("file")RequestBody image);
```

As can be seen, the code has two encodings: the @Multipart to support image upload and @FormurlEncoded needs to be used when using the @Field annotation. So I can't work if any of these are absent YET retrofit permits only one Encoding annotation at a time.
How do I go about this? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better way after trying around.
Hope this helps any other person out there

```
@POST("notes/new")
@Multipart
Call<Note> getData (@Part ("title") String title,
                    @Part("note") String note,
                    @Header("Authorization") String auth,
                    @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                    @Part("file")RequestBody image);
```

Comment: Not working correctly, as It is creating inner strings of my params.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do both FormUrlEncoded and Multipart.

Define your interface something like this:

```
@POST("notes/new")
@Multipart
Call<Response> postFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part title,..., @Part MultipartBody.Part file,...);
```

And for every parameter that had @Field you would do this in your code where you call the service:

```
String title = "MyTitle";
final MultipartBody.Part titlePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("title", title);
```

Comment: This one is the complete answer